# Restart ntlmaps without logging out?

Tags: networking

I installed `ntlmaps` from the package repositories. Since then it starts automatically when I login. Now I had to make a setting change. The problem is that I cannot turn off the computer or logout because of some programs that I have running that I cannot stop. How can I restart `ntlmaps` so that it is aware of the new settings, without logging out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run:

```
/etc/init.d/ntlmaps restart
```

at the terminal.